# Why does .val() cause an error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I want to do with my code is to use information from an input box in other parts of the webpage or data validation. From my understanding, I have to use something to the effect of, for example:

```
<script>
    var value = $('input').val();
    alert(value);
</script>
```

But when I try to use this block of code, Chrome's console is telling me the error message "*Uncaught Reference Error: $ is not defined*," but I don't know why. If it helps, the following is my code:

JS:

```
click = function() {
var password = $('input#password').val();
alert(password);
};
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="password">
<input type="submit" onClick="click();">
```

If anybody could please explain why this error is occurring, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you included jQuery ?

Comment: To add to @mohkhan's comment, did you wrap your code in the DOM ready callback like `$(function(){})`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$()` is a javascript function that's defined by the **jQuery** library.
(It's just like any other function - `foo()`, for example... it's just named with a single `$`)

The example you're working from looks like it's written to use jQuery, so you need to make sure you include jQuery on your page before you run your code.

Try adding this line at the top of your document (in the `<head>` section if possible):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

There are other libraries that sometimes use the `$` name as well - [prototype](http://prototypejs.org/), for example - and having multiple libraries fighting over the `$` name can sometimes give you similar looking errors. There are [techniques you can use](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) to help avoid conflicts like that.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize I had to include that line. However, the console is telling me now that it failed to load the resource. Why is this?

Comment: @user2636428 Are you running this page off your local files?

Comment: Yes, I am. Does this mean I have to, say, save the text in notepad and reference that?

Comment: @user2636428 Loading the page locally (via `file:` protocol) will cause that URL to use the `file:` protocol (since the URL starts with just `//`, meaning "use parent page's protocol"), which certainly won't find the jQuery file. Try putting `http:` at the front of the URL (but using no protocol for files served up on a server is usually good practice, so that it dynamically uses `http:` or `https:` as needed).

Comment: Thanks! That fixes that, so now there are no errors! (Yay!) But now, nothing happens. I can probably troubleshoot that on my own, though, so thanks for everybody's help!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function(){

var value = $('input').val();
    alert(value);

    click = function() {
      var password = $('input#password').val();
      alert(password);
    };
});
```

Comment: This will not help. The `click()` function is only run after clicking on a link - thee's no document-ready issue here. In fact, this will just mask the `click` name itself so it's not available in the HTML.